# Angular cant unsubscribe to subscription ".unsbscribe is not a function"

Tags: angular, rxjs

## My TS function

```
getMessages() {
    console.log('**** this._messages => ', this._messages);
    if (this._messages) { this._messages.unsbscribe(); }
    this._messages = this.db.get(`/users/${this.uid}/messages`).subscribe(data => {...});
}
```

## On 2nd attempt to run that function

it should open a new and close the old subscription (browser console screenshot)... `unsubscribe` looks like a function to me

[image]

## Question

Why does the console say

> this._messages.unsbscribe is not a function

if it is a function (see screenshot).... Problem i have now is there are 2 subscriptions open and i want the prev to close as the new opens

Comment: `unsbscribe` and `unsubscribe` are different words.

Comment: unsbscribe is not a function but `unsubcribe` probably is - you have a typo

Comment: omg dumb mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your spelling: .unsbscribe() is misspelled. it should be .uns**u**bscribe(